# Yearly conditional sum in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a below table

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|  Yr  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | PQR |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| 2012 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   2 |
| 2012 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |   4 |
| 2013 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |   6 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   8 |
| 2012 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   7 |
| 2013 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |   3 |
| 2014 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   2 |
| 2012 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |  10 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |  12 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

The output I want is as below

```
+------+-------+------+------+------+
|      | Total | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
| col1 |    17 |    9 |    6 |    2 |
| col2 |    23 |   14 |    9 |    0 |
| col3 |    29 |    9 |    6 |   14 |
| col4 |    17 |    9 |    6 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
```

For row `col1` in my output table

```
The column `Total` is `SUM(PQR)` when `col1` is 1 my input table

The value `17` is `SUM(PQR)` when `col1` is 1 in my input table

The value in  col `2012` is `SUM(PQR)` when `col1` is 1 and `Yr=2012` in my input table

The value `9` is `SUM(PQR)` when `col1` is 1 and `Yr=2012` in my input table
```

Similarly `6` in column `2013` is `SUM(PQR)` when `col1` is 1 and `Yr` is `2013`

Hope the process to get output table is understood

I want to achieve the above result with SAS.
Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose the data into a categorical form and use `PQR` as a weight in your aggregating sum.  `Proc TABULATE` is very adept at creating such tabulations.

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm='|'; input
   Yr    col1   col2   col3   col4   PQR ; datalines;
| 2012 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   2 |
| 2012 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |   4 |
| 2013 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |   6 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   8 |
| 2012 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   7 |
| 2013 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |   3 |
| 2014 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |   2 |
| 2012 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |  10 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |  12 |
| 2014 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |   5 |
run;

data have_row_id / view=have_row_id;
  set have;
  rowid+1;
run;

proc transpose data=have_row_id out=have_categorical;
  by rowid yr pqr;
run;

proc tabulate data=have_categorical;
  class yr _name_;
  var col1;
  weight pqr;
  table _name_='', col1='' * sum=''*f=8. * (all='Total' yr='') / nocellmerge;
run;
```

The `=''` removes labelling cells and compactifies the output.

[image: Proc TABULATE output]

Comment: Thanks Works perfect :)